# Cron job on reboot not running

Tags: cron

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus ROG GL503GE (Nvidia drivers, dual boot). I have added `@reboot root echo 60 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold` on `/etc/crontab`, but still when I reboot my computer, the command does not run. I need to run this to limit my battery charging to 60% and had that command ran successfully, my charging LED would have turned from orange to white. Now I have to manually edit the file every time I reboot my computer. Any solutions how to get this running?

Comment: Wrap your command in a `bash` script, then you can easily debug. Are you using Ubuntu?Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Try it with the [`tee`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work) command.